# In IE browser showing a JavaScript error at the status bar

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

In IE browser showing a JavaScript error at the status bar.

Error message is:

> Done, but errors on the page(Object doesn't support this property of method)
>       file: file_name.jsp
>       line number: 200

but there are not any js code at `line number 200` in `file_name.jsp`.

How to find this bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will not find any js code in file_name.jsp two ways you can find your error is by

- opening up f12 window set start debubbing to on and see where the error occurs
- or you can right click your page on the browser and view source and goto line 200 and see if you can find any js code.

i suggest you do debugg in f12 and see if you find any error

Comment: i can't debug the page, because if open only one time, if i am trying to debug the page is redirect to cart page (page is product thank you page)

Comment: i am not sure why you cant debug! if there is some redirection happening, why dont you comment the redirection untill you fix this issue ?

Comment: @K.K: look at the dev-tools window, at the top of the left side of the window (the side that shows your code) you should see a btn `Start debugging`. The page will then refresh, and the debugging button will then say `Stop debugging`.

Comment: i can't debug the page but your second points helps. thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can press F12 in internet explorer to open the developer tools. You can use those to jump directly to the code line where an error occured.

Comment: did you try to reload the page while the console is open?

Comment: Then it seems like there is much more broken on your website than just that single error which is shown in the status bar. I hope your deadline isn't that soon.